# Breaking up a flextable output into mini-tables

Tags: r, r-markdown, tidyverse, flextable

This might be unworkable but...

I am generating a simple `flextable` in Rmd for a Word output. The table contains only three columns with Column C used to colour fill the rows. Here is a short example

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)

data_short <- tibble::tribble(
          ~Col.A,   ~Col.B, ~Col.C,
              1L, "Item A",    "A",
              2L, "Item B",    "A",
              3L, "Item C",    "D",
              4L, "Item D",    "C",
)

data_short %>% 
  flextable() %>%
  bg(i = ~ Col.C == "C", j = 1:3, bg = '#FF9999',  part = "body") %>% 
  bg(i = ~ Col.C == "D", j = 1:3, bg = '#FF0000',  part = "body")
```

[image: Short example]

The problem is that I'm likely to have much more than 5 rows. Now, I don't want the output to be just a page with one big long table such as this...

```
data_long <- tibble::tribble(
               ~Col.A,   ~Col.B, ~Col.C,
                   1L, "Item A",    "A",
                   2L, "Item B",    "A",
                   3L, "Item C",    "D",
                   4L, "Item D",    "C",
                   5L, "Item E",    "A",
                   6L, "Item F",    "A",
                   7L, "Item G",    "A",
                   8L, "Item H",    "B",
                   9L, "Item I",    "C",
                  10L, "Item J",    "B",
                  11L, "Item K",    "A",
                  12L, "Item L",    "A",
                  13L, "Item M",    "D",
                  14L, "Item N",    "C",
                  15L, "Item O",    "D"
               )

data_long %>% 
  flextable() %>%
  bg(i = ~ Col.C == "C", j = 1:3, bg = '#FF9999',  part = "body") %>% 
  bg(i = ~ Col.C == "D", j = 1:3, bg = '#FF0000',  part = "body")
```

[image: Long example]

Rather, I like to be able to break up the table somehow. Split it across three mini-tables and make the maximum use of the space on the page. Something like this...
[image: What I want]

Is this even possible or am I asking for too much here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using function `tabulator()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attachement du package : 'dplyr'
#> Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> Les objets suivants sont masqués depuis 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(flextable)

data_long <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Col.A, ~Col.B, ~Col.C,
  1L, "Item A", "A",
  2L, "Item B", "A",
  3L, "Item C", "D",
  4L, "Item D", "C",
  5L, "Item E", "A",
  6L, "Item F", "A",
  7L, "Item G", "A",
  8L, "Item H", "B",
  9L, "Item I", "C",
  10L, "Item J", "B",
  11L, "Item K", "A",
  12L, "Item L", "A",
  13L, "Item M", "D",
  14L, "Item N", "C",
  15L, "Item O", "D") %>%
  mutate(
    group = cut(
      seq_len(n()), 3, labels = paste("Set", 1:3))
  ) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(row = seq_len(n()))
data_long
#> # A tibble: 15 × 5
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>    Col.A Col.B  Col.C group   row
#>    <int> <chr>  <chr> <fct> <int>
#>  1     1 Item A A     Set 1     1
#>  2     2 Item B A     Set 1     2
#>  3     3 Item C D     Set 1     3
#>  4     4 Item D C     Set 1     4
#>  5     5 Item E A     Set 1     5
#>  6     6 Item F A     Set 2     1
#>  7     7 Item G A     Set 2     2
#>  8     8 Item H B     Set 2     3
#>  9     9 Item I C     Set 2     4
#> 10    10 Item J B     Set 2     5
#> 11    11 Item K A     Set 3     1
#> 12    12 Item L A     Set 3     2
#> 13    13 Item M D     Set 3     3
#> 14    14 Item N C     Set 3     4
#> 15    15 Item O D     Set 3     5

colfun <- function(z) {
  cols <- rep("transparent", length(z))
  cols[z %in% "C"] <- "#FF9999"
  cols[z %in% "D"] <- "#FF0000"
  cols
}


tab <- tabulator(
  x = data_long,
  rows = "row",
  columns = "group",
  `Col A` = as_paragraph(Col.A),
  `Col B` = as_paragraph(Col.B),
  `Col C` = as_paragraph(Col.C),
)

visibles_a <- tabulator_colnames(tab, columns = "Col A", type = "columns")
visibles_b <- tabulator_colnames(tab, columns = "Col B", type = "columns")
visibles_c <- tabulator_colnames(tab, columns = "Col C", type = "columns")

hidden_a <- tabulator_colnames(tab, columns = "Col.A", type = "hidden")
hidden_b <- tabulator_colnames(tab, columns = "Col.B", type = "hidden")
hidden_c <- tabulator_colnames(tab, columns = "Col.C", type = "hidden")

ft <- as_flextable(tab)
ft <- bg(
  x = ft,
  j = visibles_c,
  bg = colfun,
  source = hidden_c,
  part = "body"
) %>%
  bg(
    j = visibles_b,
    bg = colfun,
    source = hidden_c,
    part = "body"
  ) %>%
  bg(
    j = visibles_a,
    bg = colfun,
    source = hidden_c,
    part = "body"
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Thanks David. I wasn't expecting a solution that quickly!

Just to follow up, can the output be modified afterwards? I mean, can the row column be removed? 

The tabulator class cannot be coerced back to a data.frame, so the `col_keys` argument won't do it.

Comment: yes, the output can be modified. This is what is done with bg color for example in the code. But no, you have to live with the row column with this solution. flextable does not allow yet to drop lines or columns. You can also build your own solution, pivot the columns and that's it. I just found funny to use tabulator for this, maybe there are better solutions